# Erasing records from text file after importing it to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

I know how to import a text file into MySQL database by using the command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/admin/Desktop/data.txt' INTO TABLE data
```

The above command will write the records of the file "data.txt" into the MySQL database table. My question is that I want to erase the records form the .txt file once it is stored in the database. 
For Example: If there are 10 records and at current point of time 4 of them have been written into the database table, I require that in the data.txt file these 4 records get erased simultaneously. (In a way the text file acts as a "Queue".) How can I accomplish this? Can a java code be written? Or a scripting language is to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Automating this is not too difficult, but it is also not trivial. You'll need something (a program, a script, ...) that can

- Read the records from the original file,
- Check if they were inserted, and, if they were not, copy them in another file
- Rename or delete the original file, and rename the new file to replace the original one.

There might be better ways of achieving what you want to do, but, that's not something I can comment on without knowing your goal.

Comment: How should I check if the records are inserted or not? (In MySQL)

Comment: You can execute a query to the database to see if the information is returned or not. If the file is big, this will not be efficient. But, not knowing what you want to achieve, I can't suggest something more efficient.